# Generate series of columns whose values equal the values of column in another row

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```
data = read.table(text = "teamID quiz.1.answer quiz.1.solution quiz.2.answer quiz.2.solution
          1 2 2 4 4
          1 3 2 1 4", header = T)

> data
  teamID quiz.1.answer quiz.1.solution quiz.2.answer quiz.3.solution
1      1             2               2             4               4
2      1             3               2             1               4
```

I would like to create a column for each individual on a team (individuals with the same unique teamID) that corresponds to the values of their other person on their team.  So, for example:

```
data_final = read.table(text = "teamID quiz.1.answer quiz.1.solution quiz.2.answer quiz.2.solution partner_quiz.1.answer partner_quiz.1.solution partner_quiz.2.answer partner_quiz.2.solution
          1 2 2 4 4 3 2 1 4
          1 3 2 1 4 2 2 4 4", header = T)
```

With this output:

```
> data_final
  teamID quiz.1.answer quiz.1.solution quiz.2.answer quiz.2.solution partner_quiz.1.answer partner_quiz.1.solution
1      1             2               2             4               4                     3                       2
2      1             3               2             1               4                     2                       2
  partner_quiz.2.answer partner_quiz.2.solution
1                     1                       4
2                     4                       4
```

All the relevant columns will be suffixed with either "answer" or "solution." There will only ever be two person teams.

I am able to emulate this behavior with the following code, on a per-variable basis.  However, in the actual dataset, I have over 100 quiz questions and solutions, so need to find a way to do this for variables matching a specific regex query.  Namely, quiz.[a number 1-100].answer or solution

```
data <- transform(data,partner_quiz.1.answer=ave(quiz.1.answer,teamID,FUN=rev))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know there are only ever 2 people in each group, switch the rows and then overwrite to a new block of variables:

```
nms <- names(data)[-1]
data <- data[order(data$teamID),]
data[paste0("partner_",nms)] <- data[seq_len(nrow(data)) + c(1,-1), nms]
data
#  teamID quiz.1.answer quiz.1.solution quiz.2.answer quiz.2.solution
#1      1             2               2             4               4
#2      1             3               2             1               4
#  partner_quiz.1.answer partner_quiz.1.solution partner_quiz.2.answer
#1                     3                       2                     1
#2                     2                       2                     4
#  partner_quiz.2.solution
#1                       4
#2                       4
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

a `data.table` solution:

```
dt <- data.table(df)

newcols <- paste0("partner_", names(dt)[2:5])

dt[, c(newcols) := .SD[order(-.I)], by = teamID]
```

The `c(newcols) :=` assigns to columns named as in `newcols`. It assigns the contents of `.SD`, which happens to be a subset of data (hence the SD), that in this case is the data filtered for each `teamID`. `[order(-.I)]` *reverses* the order of the subset (`.I` is the i-th element in the `teamID`-group), so `order(-.I)` will put student #2 first and #1 next. The `by` portion is quite self explanatory.

### Data used:

```
df = read.table(text = "teamID quiz.1.answer quiz.1.solution quiz.2.answer quiz.2.solution
1 2 2 4 4
1 3 2 1 4", header = T)
```

Please notice I avoided using `data` as it is the name of a function in the `utils` package.

Comment: I'm not familiar with data.table, but I'm getting ```Type of RHS ('double') must match LHS ('character'). To check and coerce would impact performance too much for the fastest cases. Either change the type of the target column, or coerce the RHS of := yourself (e.g. by using 1L instead of 1)```  Do I need to coerce the RHS to a string?  The classes are character in my actual dataset

Comment: can you paste here the results of `str(df)`?

Answer (score 2):

Using `dplyr` we can reverse the row numbers by group, rename the columns and bind this dataframe to the original one.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_cols(data, data %>%
                 group_by(teamID) %>%
                 slice(n() : 1) %>%
                 ungroup() %>%
                 select(-teamID) %>%
                 rename_all(~paste0("partner_", .)))

#  teamID quiz.1.answer quiz.1.solution quiz.2.answer quiz.2.solution partner_quiz.1.answer
#1      1             2               2             4               4                     3
#2      1             3               2             1               4                     2

#  partner_quiz.1.solution partner_quiz.2.answer partner_quiz.2.solution
#1                       2                     1                       4
#2                       2                     4                       4
```

If there are other columns and we want to select only those which end with `"solution"` or `"answer"` we can use `matches` in `select`

```
bind_cols(data, data %>%
     select(teamID, matches("answer$|solution$")) %>%
     group_by(teamID) %>%
     slice(n() : 1) %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     select(-teamID) %>%
    rename_all(~paste0("partner_", .)))
```